# Calculating percentiles of a percentage change measure in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentile

I’m trying to write a formula to calculate percentiles of percentage change to replicate what we do in Excel – has anyone ever done this before?
I’ve successfully been able to calculate percentiles of an average change using the following:
GC 50th Centile = PERCENTILEX.INC('Raw Data Combined',[Average Grade Change],0.5), but this doesn’t work for a % Reduction measure.

I’ve tried changing the format to a decimal rather than a percentage but this didn’t work either - it didn't show in a visual (which was the same matrix visual as the grade change one that did work).